# AWS EC2 stops working 10 minutes after launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I can successfully create a new EC2 instance using an AMI. Soon after launching, the EC2 is viewable through the browser and SSH. Consistently, if I try to view it 10 minutes after launch, the EC2 is completely inaccessible. This is reproducible many times and even happens with a static IP address.
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your instance is not providing your AMI what it requires. What AMI are you using, and what kind of instance are you using to host that AMI? Also, does the machine slow down when you try to access it while being connected to it? Or is it just unreachable? I will edit this post adding more information to your issue as soon as you answer to me. ( I cannot add a comment to the OP because I lack the reputation to do so; I hope you understand this ).

edit1: That AMI has quite low requirements. Could you please attach all the information required (together with the output of the required commands like `ps`, `free`… etc) in this section of the Bitnami Troubleshooting guide?

[Performance TroubleShooting](https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Servers/Troubleshooting#Performance_troubleshooting)

The most likely thing I can think of is that your region is experiencing technical issues, though I can't prove it in any way. Hopefully, the output you provide after following that guide will guide us in the right direction.

Comment: I launched the Bitnami Wordpress HVM AMI. It booted successfully and I can access it for a few minutes, then I am unable to connect. 

I tried pinging the Static IP and it times out. Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens when you use the AMI for the generic Amazon Linux or Ubuntu?  what region are you using? (so we can give you specific ids to try)  what admin method are you using? (web console, AWS-CLI, API)  are you using the root account or an IAM user?

Comment: 1. I get the same effect from other AMIs. 
2.  I am using the N. Virginia region.
3. I am using the Web console as Root

Comment: if you log in using ssh before the 10 minute period expires, does that session still work after the 10 minute period?

Comment: can you do a traceroute to the instance public IP after the 10 minute period expires?